# How can I display an array of images in HTML using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a contacts page and trying to populate the contacts image and name. I am able to display the array of names but not the array of pictures. Just the first picture is displayed.

I am also trying to align the contact and the image in one row. But the contact image is 
displayed first then the contact name is displayed.

Here goes the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function showContacts()
{
    var myContacts=["abc","def","xyz"]; // literal array

    for (var i=0;i<myContacts.length;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('contact').innerHTML += myContacts[i]+"<br>";
        //document.write(myArray[i]);
    }
}
function preloader() 
{
    var myPhoto=["some photos"]; // literal array
    // create object
    var img=document.getElementById('photo');
    // start preloading
    for(var i=0; i< myPhoto.length; i++) 
    {
        img.src += myPhoto[i]+"<br>";
        //document.write(i);
        //img.setAttribute('src',myPhoto[i]); 
     }
 } 

</SCRIPT>


<body onload="showContacts();preloader();">

<table width="100%" style="height: 100%;" border="0"><tr>
    <col colspan="1" ><image id="photo"/>

    <col  colspan="1" ><p id="contact"/>

</tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add multiple images to the page. You can do that in javascript.

```
<table width="100%" style="height: 100%;" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><p id="photos" /></td>
    <td><p id="contacts" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>


var container = document.getElementById("photos");

for (var i=0, len = myPhoto.length; i < len; ++i) {
     var img = new Image();
     img.src = myPhoto[i];
     container.appendChild(img);
}
```

UPDATE: this is a simple demo how to add multiple images to the DOM. What you probably want to achieve is that you have multiple table rows with one name & image per row. To accomplish that, you have to create/append new rows/cells using document.createElement (or a framework like jQuery).

UPDATE 2 - added a demo which adds multiple rows (one per contact):

http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/WRgjv/

Comment: thanks :) worked perfectly fine . Just the one which i needed .

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, you need something like:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col ...>
  <colgroup>
    <col ...>
  <tr>
    <td><img id="image0" ...>
    <td><p id="contact0" ...>
  <tr>
    <td><img id="image1" ...>
    <td><p id="contact1" ...>
  ...
</table>
```

Read the HTML 4.01 specification for [table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE) elements and use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check markup.

The "preloader" script is not doing what you might think, roberkules' answer is on the right track.